# pre commit Hook for blocking commit larger than 20MB

Tags: svn, hook

IS it possible to write prcommit hook for SVN 1.8 to avoid commiting files larger than ~20MB. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks !
I tried this but this is not working for binary files or other file extensions

```
filesize=$($SVNLOOK cat -t $TXN $REPOS $f|wc -c)
if [ "$filesize" -gt "$MAX_SIZE"]
then
    echo "File $f is too large(must <=$MAX_SIZE)" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Answer to your literal question: yes. What are you really asking? I.e., what have you tried? What is giving you trouble?

Comment: Yes, I tried but didnt succeed, Shall I use "svnlook changed" command and then calculate file size for each output of svnlook.Please guide

Comment: *What* did you try? *What* did not succeed? What did you expect to happen, and what happened instead? Or, what does your script need to do, that you are having trouble figuring out how to make that happen?

Comment: @Ben : Edited my question.Please suggest

Comment: I dont know why my question' reputation was degraded ,this is not a professional way . Someone has to give a chance to modify question .Moreever , you cannot expect everyone to be pro at everything.

Comment: Much better question, now. Before it was edited, your question was probably downvoted, because it did not give enough detail to actually answer much of anything. Hopefully it will get up-voted again now that you have added some detail, but that doesn't always happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to do two things here:

- First use `svn -t$TXN changed` to get the paths that were changed in the transaction. You need to filter out directories which would be any line returned by `svn changed` that ends with a `/`.
- For each entry from `svn changed`, you need to run `svn -t$TXN filesize file` against it. Then, sum up the file changes.

Something like this. This isn't tested, but should give you an idea:

```
total=0
svnlook -t $TXN changed | while read status file
do
    [[ status == "D" ]] && continue  # Ignore deletions
    [[ $file == */ ]] && continue    # Skip directories
    size=$(svnlook -t $TXN filesize $REPOS $file)
    ((total+=size))
done
if [[ $total -gt $maxsize ]]
then
    echo "Commit is too big!" >&2
    exit 1
else
    exit 0
fi
```

However, I don't like using shell for hook scripts. Instead, you should use a true scripting language like Python or Perl. They're simply easier to work with and are more powerful and flexible.

Why are you having to filter out these big commits? Are you getting developers trying to commit the executable they've just built?

---

Lazy badger pointed out that you're not talking about total commit size, but just a single file being that large. If this is the case, you'd do a similar hook, but without totaling:

```
svnlook -t $TXN changed | while read status file
do
    [[ $status == "D" ]] && continue  # Skip Deletions
    [[ $file == */ ]] && continue     # Skip directories
    size=$(svnlook -t $TXN filesize $REPOS $file)
    if [ $size -gt $maxsize ]]
    then
        echo "File '$file' too large to commit" >&2
        exit 2
    fi
done
exit 0
```

Comment: 1. `svnlook`, not `svn` 2. I don't think $total is good idea (you can have oversized valid commit with a lot of small files), because "committing giant shit" may be task of hook

Comment: You're right about `svnlook`. It was hard to see what OP was trying to prevent. It looked like from the OP's initial hook that the goal was to prevent commits larger than 20Mb. If the goal is to prevent really big files from being committed, then you wouldn't need a total.

Comment: overlooked: in `filesize` command you miss $REPOS parameter: `svnlook -t $TXN filesize $REPOS $file` must be final right syntax

Comment: @Brandon - Your suggested edit of this answer would be better as its own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Read `svnlook help`

Use `svnlook changed` + `svnlook filesize`

**Explanation for sluggards**

`$SVNLOOK filesize -t $TXN $REPOS $f` will "... print the size (in bytes) of the file located at $f".

Sample for test-repo's HEAD state

```
>svnlook filesize Repo trunk/ADExplorer.exe
479096
```

If you want to check every file in transaction in pre-commit hook, you have to:

Get list of all objects in  transaction (`svnlook changed -t ...`)

```
>svnlook changed Repo
A   trunk/ADExplorer.exe
A   trunk/Hlp/
A   trunk/Hlp/AdExplorer.chm
```

Skip all non-file entities from list, because

```
>svnlook filesize Repo trunk/Hlp/
svnlook: E160017: Path 'trunk/Hlp' is not a file
```

Pass every object of pure file-list to `svnlook filesize` and test returned number

Comment: Svnlook changed give files changed which are committed in svn and same with file size.I dont think we're should use file size here as file is not committed.Any detailed  help will he appreciated .

Comment: @Kaku - **RTFM!!!** *Any* svnlook subcommand can be used with `-t` parameter for transactions (at pre-commit stage), where transaction's objects are not part of history yet

Answer (score 2):

Analyzing file size with `svnlook` is not always the best approach when the task is to check the size of incoming transaction. Your repository might be already having "large" files and the users may be committing changes to them. Using `svnlook filesize` without any special logic in pre-commit hook script will reject modifications to those files.

To avoid such problems, what about checking the size of the incoming transaction on disk? Here is a sample pre-commit hook script written in PowerShell. It check's the total size of incoming transaction in `$repos\db\txn-protorevs\$txn.rev` and rejects the commit if it's larger than 100MB.

***pre-commit.ps1***

```powershell
# Store hook arguments into variables with mnemonic names
$repos    = $args[0]
$txn      = $args[1]

# Put commit size limit in bytes
$limit = 1000000

# Prepare error message
$errortxt = ("Commits larger than 100MB are forbidden.")

# Check the size of $txn.rev file and deny the commit if larger than $limit
$item = Get-Item "$repos\db\txn-protorevs\$txn.rev"

if ($item.Length -gt $limit){
  [Console]::Error.WriteLine($errortxt)
  exit 3
}
exit 0
```

Hook scripts written in PowerShell should be started from a Windows Batch script. Here is an example:

***pre-commit.bat***

```powershell
set PWSH=%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe

%PWSH% -command $input ^| %1\hooks\pre-commit.ps1 %1 %2

if errorlevel 1 exit %errorlevel%
```

Answer (score 1):

The current answers to this question do not work on our svn server. Maybe something has changed in subversion in the meantime.

This is how our `post-commit` hook is configured:

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
MAXSIZE=1048576

# we don't want anyone to know if something went wrong
svnlook changed -r $REV $REPOS | while read status file
do
  [[ $status == "D" ]] && continue  # Skip Deletions
  [[ $file == */ ]] && continue     # Skip directories
  size=$(svnlook filesize -r $REV $REPOS $file)
  if [ $size -gt $MAXSIZE ]]
  then
    #do something if the file is larger than MAXSIZE, in our case just write that file, size and revision to a file
    echo "File '$file' with size '$size' too large to commit.REV: '$REV'" >/tools/svnrepos/file-commits-big-size.txt
  fi
done
```